# click the generated button while loop does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list that receives dynamic data mysql database, the list returns me some youtube links with Title thumbnail and full view of each video, I made a simple script that displays and hides a div using css disply none and display block this div that will receive the link and it will display the video, my problem is that only the first play button hides and shows the div, the other buttons dynamically created in while not working.

Here is my HTML and PHP receiving the data bank through while

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="divvideos">
    <ul>
        <?php while($videolist = $resultvideos->fetch_array()){ ?>
        <li class="listdivvideos">
            <button class="btplay" id="btplay"></button>
            <img src="images/datahoraicon.png" class="imgdatahora">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $videolist['miniatura'] ?>/default.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the simple script to show and hide the div player

```
<script>
    $("#btplay").click(function () {
        if($("#player").css("display") == "none")
            $("#player").css("display","block");
        else
            $("#player").css("display","none");
    });
</script>
```

My code works normally by clicking the button with the ID btplay it hides and shows the div with the id player, my only problem is that this button is created several times because the While it is created in the home line that returns the while but only the primero button hides and shows the div other buttons do not work

Comment: `id`'s should be unique. if you are creating multiple element with the same id, which would you expect it to select? try `$('.btnplay').on('click', () => {});`

Comment: Can you show part of code with `#player`?

Comment: Also if you're using jquery, you can use $("#player").toggle() to show/hide them instead of the if block.

Comment: @atmd  It worked like a glove, I really did not pay attention that was created with the ID instead of Class. @ Boris Savic the player code is not ready yet but post here when you're ready, you can put the answer to Question answer for me to choose how correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your **Ids** should be **unique** (as mentioned above). Leave them out or add a counter to it (better leave them out).

```
$(".btplay").click(function () {
```

should make the trick.

Tipp: You could replace

```
 <?php while($videolist = $resultvideos->fetch_array()){ ?>
      //...
 <?php } ?>
```

with

```
 <?php while($videolist = $resultvideos->fetch_array()): ?>
      //...
 <?php endwile; ?>
```

And

```
 <?php echo $videolist['miniatura'] ?>
```

with

```
 <?= $videolist['miniatura']; ?>
```

I think it makes it more readable, but it is just a tipp.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `<?=` maybe disabled in your php conf